# What is the correct way to ensure unique entries in a temporal database design?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, t-sql, trigger

I'm having trouble with the design of a temporal database. I need to know how to make sure I have only one active record for any given timeframe for a store. I have read [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56605/37401), but I'm afraid I can't wrap my head around how the trigger would work. Particularly, how I would work that trigger into my existing one that prevents updates to records, and inserts a new record instead. My real problem is that I do not know how to prevent a Store from having more than one effective date when the finished date is null. (i.e. prevent 2 active records for a store).

This is what I have, but it allows me to insert a new record for a store with a different effective date.

Table Definition:

```
/****** Object:  Table [PCR].[Z_STORE_TEAM]    Script Date: 05/09/2014 13:05:57 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[Z_STORE_TEAM]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [Z_STORE_TEAM]
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[Z_STORE_TEAM]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [Z_STORE_TEAM](
    [STORENUM] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TEAM] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [EFFECTIVE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [FINISHED] [date] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [STORENUM] ASC,
    [EFFECTIVE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
```

Sample Data:

```
INSERT [Z_STORE_TEAM] ([STORENUM], [TEAM], [EFFECTIVE], [FINISHED]) VALUES (1, N'1', CAST(0x01380B00 AS Date), CAST(0x81380B00 AS Date))
INSERT [Z_STORE_TEAM] ([STORENUM], [TEAM], [EFFECTIVE], [FINISHED]) VALUES (1, N'2', CAST(0x81380B00 AS Date), NULL)
INSERT [Z_STORE_TEAM] ([STORENUM], [TEAM], [EFFECTIVE], [FINISHED]) VALUES (2, N'1', CAST(0x01380B00 AS Date), NULL)
INSERT [Z_STORE_TEAM] ([STORENUM], [TEAM], [EFFECTIVE], [FINISHED]) VALUES (2, N'2', CAST(0x20380B00 AS Date), NULL)
```

Instead of Update Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [tr_ZStoreTeam_update] 
   ON  [Z_STORE_TEAM]
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    INSERT INTO PCR.Z_STORE_TEAM(STORENUM,TEAM,EFFECTIVE)
    SELECT I.STORENUM,I.TEAM,GETDATE() AS EFFECTIVE
    FROM inserted I
    INNER JOIN PCR.Z_STORE_TEAM ST
        ON I.STORENUM = ST.STORENUM

    UPDATE ST
    SET FINISHED = GETDATE()
    FROM PCR.Z_STORE_TEAM ST
    INNER JOIN inserted I
        ON ST.STORENUM = I.STORENUM
        AND ST.EFFECTIVE = I.EFFECTIVE
END

GO
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The safest way to do this is to enforce your business rules using the built-in referential integrity constraints, as Alexander Kuznetsov describes in his article, ["Storing intervals of time with no overlaps"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180424214356/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/03/08/storing-intervals-of-time-with-no-overlaps.aspx).

Applying the techniques listed there to your sample table results in the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE [Z_STORE_TEAM](
    [STORENUM] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TEAM] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [EFFECTIVE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [FINISHED] [date] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [STORENUM] ASC,
        [EFFECTIVE] ASC
    )
) ON [PRIMARY];

INSERT [Z_STORE_TEAM] 
    ([STORENUM], [TEAM], [EFFECTIVE], [FINISHED]) 
VALUES 
    (1, N'1', CAST(0x01380B00 AS Date), CAST(0x81380B00 AS Date)),
    (1, N'2', CAST(0x81380B00 AS Date), NULL),
    (2, N'1', CAST(0x01380B00 AS Date), NULL);
```

Modifications:

```
-- New column to hold the previous finish date
ALTER TABLE dbo.Z_STORE_TEAM 
ADD PreviousFinished date NULL;
GO
-- Populate the previous finish date
UPDATE This
SET PreviousFinished = Previous.FINISHED
FROM dbo.Z_STORE_TEAM AS This
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP (1) 
        Previous.FINISHED
    FROM dbo.Z_STORE_TEAM AS Previous
    WHERE 
        Previous.STORENUM = This.STORENUM
        AND Previous.FINISHED <= This.EFFECTIVE
    ORDER BY 
        Previous.FINISHED DESC
) AS Previous;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Z_STORE_TEAM 
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_STORENUM_PreviousFinished
UNIQUE (STORENUM, PreviousFinished);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Z_STORE_TEAM
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_PreviousFinished_NotAfter_Effective
CHECK (PreviousFinished = EFFECTIVE);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Z_STORE_TEAM
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_STORENUM_FINISHED
UNIQUE (STORENUM, FINISHED);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Z_STORE_TEAM
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_STORENUM_PreviousFinished
FOREIGN KEY (STORENUM, PreviousFinished)
REFERENCES dbo.Z_STORE_TEAM (STORENUM, FINISHED);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Z_STORE_TEAM
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_EFFECTIVE_Before_FINISHED
CHECK (EFFECTIVE < FINISHED);
```

An attempt to insert the fourth row of sample data now fails with an error message:

```
INSERT [Z_STORE_TEAM] 
    ([STORENUM], [TEAM], [EFFECTIVE], [FINISHED]) 
VALUES 
    (2, N'2', '20140201', NULL);
```

[image: Error message]

Please read Alex's article to understand how these constraints ensure your table data will always be valid. Having a set of constraints enforce your data integrity means no trigger code is required.

Related article by the same author:

[Modifying Contiguous Time Periods in a History Table](https://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=1191)